# Speech to text on an outbound call using gather with a free trial account of Twilio

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am trying to create a sample project where twilio will make an outbound call to my phone number and ask a question, I will reply the answer, and twilio will reply my answer back to me. But after I say my answer, it says,"An application error has occured, goodbye".

I am using a trial account to test things out before upgrading to do a main project. Am I getting the error because of free trial??

```
Following is the sample code:


client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

response = VoiceResponse()
gather = Gather(input='speech', action='/process_response')
gather.say('Hello, how are you?')
response.append(gather)

call = client.calls.create(
    twiml = str(response),
    to = to_number,
    from_ = from_number
)


from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process_response', methods=['POST'])
def process_response():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    response.say('Your answer was: ' + request.form['SpeechResult'])
    return str(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the Twilio Console -> Monitor and find the error logs and calls to find more information about the error and debug your issue.
[image: Twilio Console navigation to find error logs and calls under monitor tab.]

My guess is that the response content-type is not set to application/xml or text/xml, but I haven't worked with Flask myself. Either way, dig through the error logs/calls to find the issue and let us know!